# Php sorting multidimensional child array key value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array with multidimensional array like i have splited the large size array into chunk of pieces and am trying to apply sorting like asc and desc...The array function like array_multisort, usort i have tried but it not at all working as i expected results..

The array is

```
 <pre>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rate] => 16.8
                    [details] => Array
                        (
                            [address] => 280 Lavender Street
                            [city] => Singapore


                        )

                    [packages] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (

                                [avg_rate] => 16.8
                            )

                    )

            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [rate] => 16.8
                [details] => Array
                    (
                        [address] => 280 Lavender Street
                        [city] => Singapore


                    )

                [packages] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (

                                [avg_rate] => 16.8
                            )

                    )

            )    
            ...
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [rate] => 16.8
                [details] => Array
                    (
                        [address] => 280 Lavender Street
                        [city] => Singapore


                    )

                [packages] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (

                                [avg_rate] => 16.8
                            )

                    )

            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [rate] => 16.8
                [details] => Array
                    (
                        [address] => 280 Lavender Street
                        [city] => Singapore


                    )

                [packages] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (

                                [avg_rate] => 16.8
                            )

                    )

            )    
            ...
    )
```

and the function i have

```
usort($result['list'], function($a, $b) {
                    if($a['packages'][0]['avg_rate'] == $b['packages'][0]['avg_rate'])
                        return 0;

                    return $a['packages'][0]['avg_rate'] < $b['packages'][0]['avg_rate'] ? -1 : 1;
                });
```

Any suggestion

Comment: I am guessing that the array you pasted in stored in $result['list']... This means you are sorting the top most array. You'll want to loop through it and sort all subarrays, like $result['list'][0] this will sort all groups. But will not sort between groups, you'd need to concatenate the arrays first, sort and re-explode it.

Comment: what do you want? From your sort function, I don't think it has any relation with multiple dimension. You are still sorting a single dimension array, just the element is also an array.

Comment: @iamnoten : I'm trying to sort the group of dimensional array.

Comment: What results are you expecting? By looking at your example, data of the arrays are the same. Thus, it's already sorted. It would help if you give more samples of your code.